# How can I split apart a string that has different amount of spaces into two parts?

Tags: java

I wanted to split one half to be a String mimeType and second half to be String ext

so far I implemented (str being the individual lines)

```
String mimeType="";
String ex = "";

String[] strArr = str.split("\t\t\t");

mimeType = strArr[0];
ex = strArr[1];
```

Since some don't have a second part, I keep getting errors. How do I go about fixing that?

```
audio/vnd.octel.sbc
audio/vnd.qcelp
audio/vnd.rhetorex.32kadpcm
audio/vnd.vmx.cvsd
audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin rpm
audio/x-realaudio       ra
audio/x-wav         wav
chemical/x-pdb          pdb
chemical/x-xyz          xyz
image/bmp           bmp
image/cgm           cgm
image/g3fax
image/gif           gif
image/ief           ief
image/jpeg          jpeg jpg jpe
```

Answer (score 2):

Just check the length of the array:

```
String[] strArr = str.split("\t\t\t");
mimeType = strArr[0];

if(strArr.length >= 2) {
    ex = strArr[1];
} else {
    ex = "None";
}
```

Comment: This helped a lot but I'm still stuck here. I did split it in half, however I want to store the second part all in "ext". For example I wanna grab the second half  "jpeg jpg jpe" and store it in "ext". If that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Use `\\s+` to split on spaces even if they're are multiple.

```java
String mimeType="";
String ex = "";

String[] strArr = str.split("\\s+");

mimeType = strArr[0];
ex = strArr[1];
```